# Easy Bash Cut Delimiter

Tags: bash

I have this..

```
$input = "echo     a       b                c   d"
echo -e "$input" | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

but I just want a simple cut that will get rid of echo as well as print

```
a b c d #(single space) only
```

Comment: bash is not Perl: you don't use a dollar sign on the left-hand side of an assignment, and you cannot have spaces around the equal sign: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters

Comment: If you `echo $input` without quotes, all multiple spaces are gone. Hence, you can do `echo $input | cut -d' ' -f2-`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo -e "$input" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d " " -f2-
```

Also gets rid of the 'echo'.

Comment: with bash, you can use a "here-string": `tr -s " " <<<"$input" | cut -d " " -f2-`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any tools besides what bash provides built-in.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ input="echo     a       b                c   d"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ output=${input//  / }
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo $output
echo a b c d
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo ${output#* }
a b c d
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Up-side: you avoid the extra overhead of pipes.

Down-side: you need to assign an extra variable, because you can't do complex pattern expansion within complex pattern expansion (i.e. `echo ${${input//  / }#* }` won't work).

Answer (score 3):

A little roundabout, but interesting:

```
( set -- $input; shift; echo $@ )
```

Comment: In general, always quote `"$@"` -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters

Comment: True. In this case, I didn't bother to correct it after I'd clicked post since the original question only asked for the resulting string with the spaces collapsed. But since quoting wouldn't have changed anything and protected the string if it did matter, I should have.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed -e 's/[ ]*[^ ]*[ ]*\(.*\)/\1/' -e 's/[ ]*/ /g' -e 's/^ *//' input_file
```